# Should upvoting the "Possible duplicate of..." comment mark the question as duplicate?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-questions

When someone flags a question as duplicate, a comment is automatically created:

```
Possible duplicate of [link].
```

If someone else flags the question as duplicate with the same link, it automatically casts an upvote to that comment. However, doing the inverse action - upvoting the comment to mark it as duplicate - does not work.

**Should upvoting the "Possible duplicate of..." comment mark the question as duplicate ?**

- It would make flagging faster
- There is no reason to upvote the comment [possible duplicate of...] if you don't think the question deserves to be marked as duplicate.
- Could be a feature only available for users with a certain amount of reputation, that would also prevent new users to lazily flag the question without verifying if it really is a duplicate.

It really isn't something vital, but I don't see why it wouldn't be the case. I can't think of any issues that feature would bring.

Comment: I sometimes add manually this comment without voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Should upvoting the "Possible duplicate of..." comment mark the question as duplicate ?**

Just gain enough reputation to make duplication votes actually count for closing. Upvoting the comment is more a sign for the OP, that they should accept it, or improve their question to tell why the duplicate isn't appropriate for their question.

I don't see how such feature would improve the current process in action.

Comment: Additionally there is no way to know if that is true "duplicate" comment or someone just typed in some text that *looks* like one...

Answer (score 3):

> I can't think of any issues that feature would bring.

I can. Through the current dialogue you have to look at the whole question again, including its answers. That way you have to check that not only the question fits but it also has helpful answers (that is not always the case).

> It would make flagging faster

Dupe flagging is already fast. There are enough goldbadgers around that are dupehammering questions. The other flags are rather too slow, as they require four votes.